# IOS Google map sdk: How to make a marker info window with different links

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am developing an app which is using google map sdk. I want to make the info window created on clicking marker with more than one button on it. Like one for show direction to this marker and one for show details.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't have two links on a same info window because info window as a whole acts like a button.